# about TypedArray obtainTypedArry

Tags: android, arrays, android-intent, typedarray

I wrote those two lines :

```
final  String[] options = res.getStringArray(breakFastNames);
final  TypedArray icons = res.obtainTypedArray(R.array.breakFastIcons);
```

The first one is working. But the second one is giving an error when I put it inside `putExtra`:

```
mIntent.putExtra("OPTIONS",options[i]);
mIntent.putExtra("ICONS", icons[i]);
```

Kindly if someone is able to solve this issue, that will be strongly appreciated.

Comment: What's the error traceback ?

Comment: error: array required, but TypedArray found

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A `TypedArray` is an instance of the class `TypedArray`, it is not a Java array, so you cannot reference a single value of the array using `[i]`.

Assuming that `icons` is an array of `Drawable`, use this instead:

```
mIntent.putExtra("OPTIONS",options[i]);
mIntent.putExtra("ICONS", icons.getDrawable(i));
```

Comment: thank you for the replay , actually ICON is an array from XML values file . i used your method getDrwable  , but i got another error saying that Drwable cant be converted .

Comment: What is the type of the variable in `icons`? If they are `int`s then you should use `icons.getInt(i, -1)` instead. You can paste your XML file in the question.

Comment: Thank you very much , this one works like magic  , well you please tell what is the best method to receive data in the next activity . thanks again .

Comment: Galad this fixed your problem. I don't understand what you mean by "best method to receive data in the next activity". If you have another problem, please post a new question. It is better to keep separate issues separately.  But first search to see if there is already an answer to be found.

Comment: Also, as you are new on Stackoverflow, if my answer was helpful you should "accept" it by clicking the green checkmark next to the answer. This will help both me and you and will remove the question from the list of "unanswered questions".